# How to align on center the title of a section and the rest of the text fully justify?

Tags: align

I would like to align my title on the center but have the rest of the text justify.
I would like to do this on the top and not in each specific section.

[image]

packages that i am using

```
\documentclass[14 pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,width = 7in, height = 9in , left = 0.75in, top = 1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.24in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\centering}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing what you have tried so far. Usuallu, "do my task for me", questions are frowned upon. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Why don't you just use \abstract and \noindent or \parindent=0pt?

Comment: Do let us know which document class you use, and whether or not you use any packages such as `sectsty` and `titlesec` that simplify influencing the appearance of sectioning headers. And, should the words in the section headers be set in all-uppercase and bold, as your screenshot would seem to imply?

Comment: Is this specific to an abstract, or a general section within an article?

Comment: No, no that wasn't my intention, the reason i didn't post my code it is because i am a beginner and i have used a lot of unused packages and i wanted to keep the post as simple as much. About the documents does not has to do with me. It is a random text.

Comment: @Werner it is for the whole document

Comment: @Mico , yes it should be in bold. My screenshot is from MS word

Comment: Thank you very much with helping me ask questions with the right way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated which document class you use, so my answer will have to be quite basic. (Depending on the document class that's in use, more specialized methods may be available.)

- By default, LaTeX typesets the body of a document fully justified, so there's nothing special you need to do in this regard.
- To center-set section-level headers, you could load the [sectsty](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package (via the instruction `\usepackage{sectsty}`, to be issued in the preamble, and issue the instruction (also in the preamble):

  ```
  \sectionfont{\centering}
  ```

  Note that this instruction does not influence other aspects of a section-level header, such as the font size, the weight (normal versus bold), the shape (upright versus italics), or the case (all-uppercase, small caps, or font case as input).

Comment: Although my section title is aligned correct, the rest of the text in the sections is still aligned on the left. Any thoughts?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Molnia -- you need to comment out (or delete) the instruction `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}`. At the very least, you need to remove the option `document` from this instruction since you do not want to set the document in ragged-right (also known as flush-left) mode.

Comment: That solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated which TeX macro you use, so I suppose that it is plain TeX. Then you can define the `\section` macro and use it:

```
\def\section#1\par{\bigskip{\noindent\bf\hfil#1\par}\nobreak\medskip}

\section Abstract

here is text

\bye
```

Note the `\hfil` inside the definition. It does the centering. We assume (for simplicity) that the title is no longer than the line.

Comment: I am going to write a two column paper-like article. Do not know if that helps with the TeX macro. The section is aligned correctly but the main body of the text throught out the article keeps left side alignment.